# Look at what functions are being called Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

There are several posts with similar question as mine but none seem to answer my issue. I am currently working to reverse engineer a site where a JavaScript file is being loaded in under `sources`. For example purposes I will refer to it as `foo.js`. This script is generating a cookie that I need. I will refer to it as `bar`. `foo.js` is actively generating a new `bar` cookie everytime I refresh the cookies tab under `Application` in Chrome dev tools meaning its being generating at least every second by `foo.js`.

The catch is that `foo.js` is heavily obfuscated with enterprise security where I cannot do a simple `CTRL + F` and look for `document.cookie`. But that isn't really relevant anyways. What I'm wondering is, surley a function is being ran to generate this since it's not hardcoded so how can I see what functions are being ran?

I have tried setting breakpoints in the code but there are over 15,000 lines of code so it's a bit inefficient. I have also tried pausing script execution and looking at the Call Stack and there are functions being executed from `foo.js` but it's very vague on what these functions are returning. Additionally I don't think the functions I'm seeing are the correct one's because they only show up when I visit certain pages whereas the `bar` cookie is being generated constantly no matter what page I'm on.

Is there any clear way to simply see what functions are being executed in the background and what they're returning? Specifically involving cookies. I feel like this should be a simple feature but I can seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at page start and run debug(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie').set)

Comment: My apologies for responding this late, but I've just got the time to try this now. When I Put this in console I just get `undefined`. What would that mean? Thanks in advanced. @wOxxOm

Comment: This command doesn't return anything so `undefined` is the correct result. The point is that it'll trigger debugger if there's any code that sets document.cookie. The important thing is to do it on page start, not after it loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working :) @wOxxOm